# How we can set min and max attribute in settings_schema.json in shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I am trying to add maximum character value for input field in settings.schema.json file. but it show me error that:

**Error: Invalid block 'slide': setting with id="title_2" 'max' is not a valid attribute**

This is my code:

```
{
    "type": "text",
    "id": "title_2",
    "label": "Title 2",
    "placeholder": "Link Title",
"max":10
  },
```

max attribute is working fine for Range type.

```
"blocks": [
{
  "type": "slide",
  "name": "Press",
  "settings": [
  {
    "type": "product",
    "id": "press_product",
    "label": "Select Product"
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "id": "title_2",
    "label": "Title 2",
    "placeholder": "Link Title",
    "max":10
  },
```

...

Please help me to solve this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: read over here
https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/theme-editor/settings-schema
seems like max is used with type='range' not with text

Comment: Yes I know about it, I just want to know is there any way to do so.

Comment: sorry but i just know that,may you can try with max length !

Comment: Okay.. I have tried with jquery but it not works as shopify create ID,Classes dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `max` attribute for fields.

The only field that accepts `max` is the range field.